# Allow Multiple Transactions on One Connection

Tags: sql-server

I have console c# program that is accessing a database.

Part of the code is doing some inserts and updates that I want to control with a transaction.  This is the part of the code that is handling the business logic.

Another part of the code is doing some inserts and updates that is more system support logic that I want to commit immediately on insert.  Specifically this code is inserting a row when the program starts and updating the row with the end.  It also logs certain events in the code.  I don't want these logged events to go away just because something failed in the business logic.

I tried to do the business logic with SqlCommand like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection, transaction);
```

and system logic like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
```

But I get this error:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when
>   connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.

My goal is to have the business logic commit only upon `transaction.Commit()` and the system logic to commit immediately.

Can I accomplish that with two separate transactions?

Will I need to open two different connections?

Comment: Why do you mean by system logic to commit immediately??? A transaction is at the database level. I think you are confused about what a transaction means in this situation. Sounds to me like you need two completely independent pieces of work. If that is the case then you should use two connections, each with their own transaction.

Comment: I think he'll need two commands as well as two connections.

Comment: Is it pretty much true that if a connection uses one SqlCommand() with a transaction then all SqlCommand()s need to have a transaction?

Comment: Is it also true that one Connection can not have more than one Transaction?

Comment: Not totally clear what your last two questions mean but if you have a command with a transaction it has no bearing on any other command. Each instance is a separate object. For the second....while you can have multiple transactions the concept of nested transactions is a myth. They do not function at all the way they seem like they should. Just don't use nested transactions and avoid the issue. Your original question seems like you might want to refactor some of your logic to avoid being overly complicated.

Comment: @MichaelPotter looks like you are looking for nested transactions: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @PabloHenkowski nested transactions are much of a myth as a unicorn. They are not real. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks. High value input! I was just considering them for production use

Answer (score 0):

In the end I created two different Connections: one for transaction based IO and another for non-transactions based IO.

I then used code that looked like this to set the transaction on each command:

```
transaction = new connection.BeginTransaction();
someCommand1.Transaction = transaction;
someCommand2.Transaction = transaction;
```

Where someCommand1/2 are SqlCommand()s previously created in the code.

This avoids the problem of calling SqlCommand multiple times.

Turned out to be very clean in the code.